# Submit closest form with Jquery on change

Tags: jquery

I have two `select boxes`, each in their own form. I want it so that when the user changes the `selectbox` value the form submits. I added some console logs for debugging and **it appears that when I change the select boxes only the first console is being shown and it never advances past the submit which leads me to believe something is wrong there but I cant figure out what!** Preemptively I was also wondering if for the post data I would have to `$(this).closest('form').serialize()` as opposed to what I currently have.

```
$('#usr_vcm, #usr_ma').change(function(){
    console.log('change triggered');
    $(this).closest('form').submit(function() {
        console.log('submit closest done');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).closest('form').attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                alert(data + 'hello');                    
            }
        });

    });           
});
```

Sample HTML

```
<form name="usr_vcm_frm" method="post" action="framework/AJAX/config_actions.php?config=view_create_modified" class="form-inline">
  <div class="controls docs-input-sizes">
    <select name="usr_vcm" class="select-ms" id="usr_vcm">
      <option value="1">Allow</option>
      <option value="0" <?php if ($row_config['usr_view_cm'] == '0') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>Do not allow</option>
    </select>
    <span style="margin-left:5px;">users to see the name of who created/modified a post</span> </div>
</form>
<form name="usr_ma_frm" method="post" action="framework/AJAX/config_actions.php?config=user_auto_active" class="form-inline">
  <div class="controls docs-input-sizes">
    <select name="usr_ma" class="select-ms" id="usr_ma">
      <option value="1">Allow</option>
      <option value="0" <?php if ($row_config['usr_auto_activ'] == '0') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>Do not allow</option>
    </select>
    <span style="margin-left:5px;">automatic activation of users after they complete the registration form <span class="error-color">(not recommended to allow)</span></span> </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You should try $(this).parent('form') or check if the form is first ancestor

Comment: no such luck :( added some HTML sample of what ive got

Comment: Try `$(this).parent().parent('form')`

Comment: nope. still nothing.

Comment: document.getElementsByName(this.id + '_frm')[0].submit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining an event handler to be called when the form is submitted, but never actually submitting the form. Review the jQuery docs on [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) for the distinctions in the method signatures. Instead define the 'submit' handler outside of your 'change' handler, and then trigger submit onchange:

```
$(function() {
    $('[name="usr_vcm_frm"], [name="usr_ma_frm"]').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('submit closest done');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                alert(data + 'hello');                    
            }
        });
    }); 

    $('#usr_vcm, #usr_ma').change(function(){
        console.log('change triggered');
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Accepted as most complete answer! Thank you

Comment: @Alex No problem! Also worth noting, the jQuery [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method will work for both `<select>` elements as well as entire `<form>` elements, but if you're planning on adding other elements to the form you might as well serialize the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $('#usr_vcm, #usr_ma').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).closest('form').attr('action'),
            data: $(this).closest('form').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                alert(data + 'hello');                    
            }
        });

});
```

Working **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/hvq0uahj/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here you are binding `submit` event, and not justy actually submitting the form, I mean:

```
$(this).closest('form').submit(function() {...
```

to submit form you have to do `$(this).closest('form').submit();` without handler.

I would do something like this to handle form submit:

```
    $('.form-inline').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log('submit closest done');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                alert(data + 'hello');                    
            }
        });
    });
```

and to submit form on change:

```
$('#usr_vcm, #usr_ma').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Upvoted as first accurate, but the accepted one was more complete. Thanks!

Comment: No prob bro, but I don't see that much difference between the answers :))